# How To Beat The Mouse Cave Red Diamond Level in Mittens iOS

Tags: mittens

In Disney's game Mittens on iOS, during the Mouse Cave area on the final Red Diamonds level, I cannot seem to get past the mine carts that are after the first red volcano geyser. I can land in the mine cart. Once the cart starts going down the track, I cannot see anything that can be done. How do you get past this point?

Answer (score 1):

After you jump on the swing above lava, immediately cut the rope to get back into the wagon otherwise the boulder will crush you, then prepare to jump out again to meet Mia on the cave balcony above. End of the Mouse Cave challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the shovel to jump in the cart (not bat and swing) then unlock other cart as soon as u can see the lock. Jump in other cart. Then jump to bat and first bird. Turn on lights. Then jump to second bird. This brings you back to the first water break. When back up where TNT was, now use bat and swing to get to upper level cart. Then you need to jump off cart to swing and over lava break. This is as far as I got. I keep getting squished by a rock at this point.